# Вывод количества вызовов рекурсивной функции

Tags: c#

Задача такова: у меня есть функция, которая принимает на вход число, мне нужно разбить это число (если оно имеет больше 1 символа) на цифры и перемножить все эти цифры. Данное действие должно повторяться пока аргумент функции не станет одноразрядным числом. Ну и вывести мне нужно количество повторений этого алгоритма. То есть к примеру если функция принимает на вход `39` то нужно вывести `3`, так как `3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4`. Если принимает на вход `999` то `4`, так как `9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126,1*2*6 = 12,1*2 = 2` и тд. Для этой задачи я написал рекурсивный алгоритм. Вот и он:

```
static int count;
public static int Persistence(long n)
{
  count++;
  int position = 0;
  int[] array = n.ToString().Select(x => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(x)).ToArray(); //здесь я разделяю число на цифры
  if (n > 10)
      return Persistence(array[position] * array[position + 1]);
  return count;
}

public static void Main()
{
   Console.WriteLine(Persistence(4));
}
```

Моя проблема такова: алгоритм правильно работает только с двухразрядными числами, но вот если разрядов в числе больше, то алгоритм работает только с первыми двумя цифрами данного числа. Пример: если я введу число 999, то программа умножит первые две цифры, в итоге получится, что `n = 81`, мне же нужно чтобы все три девятки в этом числе перемножились и число `n` стало равно `729`. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Ваш алгоритм будет неправильно работать для отрицательных чисел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, собственно, вы и написали перемножение только 2х цифр здесь:

```
return Persistence(array[position] * array[position + 1]);
```

Перемножить все:

```
var mul = array[0];
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; ++t)
    mul *= array[i];
return Persistence(mul);
```

ну, или тоже самое с помощью Linq:

```
var mul = array.Aggregate((a, b) => a * b);
return Persistence(mul);
```